# Oracle clr host

Tags: oracle, clr

I'm so new to oracle 
and I have been ordered to execute .net clr in oracle 
but I'm confused now with these concepts
oracle data access components
oracle data .net extensions
please any help to put me on the right way
how I'm going to execute clr written in .net in oracle environment 
I'm using oracle 12c and visual studio 2013

i have installed this oracle data access components 
in this link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html
for oracle 12 release1
and then 
download oracle developer tools for visual studio

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2013-2756823.html

and i'm getting errors when making new oracle project
is installation order wrong?

Comment: what about https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14306/intro.htm#BABICHJI

Comment: " is installation order wrong?" There's really no way for us to tell. If you're not confident to investigate your installation by yourself you need to swallow your pride and ask a colleague to help you. Any decent organization should have standard builds for its tool sets.

Comment: i have discovered that each release of oracle has specific corresponding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your replies 
,but
i have discovered that each release of oracle has specific corresponding ODAC (oracle Data Access Components) ,and if you install un correct one you will get a lot of problems when deploying .net stored procedure (clr)

for me with oracle 12c release 1 
the suitable odac  were  Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) For windows x 64  found in this link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html
when i installed these components i was able to have visual c# oracle project and then i followed this link tutorial

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63386/demo.htm#CLRNT154

and every thing in clr  was ok